# How to pass variable to value in dictionary

Tags: dictionary, tcl

I am new to dictionary in TCL. I have a dictionary and i have used variable to a value inside dictionary. For example

```
   set first "Varun"
   set last "Kumar"
   set name [dict create "ID_1" {prename "$first" surname "$last"}]
   set nm  [dict get $name ID_1]
   puts $nm
```

The output is giving as "prename $first surname $last".

Could you please help me how handle this

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to give an in-depth answer, perhaps others can help add to it.

In Tcl, braces prevent all substitutions, including variable substitutions.

To create a multi-level dict, you'll want to use the `list` command

```
   set name [dict create "ID_1" [list prename $first surname $last]]
   puts [dict get $name ID_1 surname]     ;# => Kumar
```

Note, it's not necessary to quote variables, unlike shell programming.

You might want to have a run through [the Tcl tutorial](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html), and the [12 rules of Tcl syntax](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

---

As Donal suggests, building piecemeal avoids all the quoting issues.

```
dict set name ID_1 prename $first
dict set name ID_1 surname $last
```

Comment: Alternatively, build it piecemeal with `dict set`.